# How to sort data alphabetically in a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 100+ records in an Excel Sheet. I want to sort data **alphabetically**. The data is separated by the "+" symbol.

*example*:

```
input :  Self + Kid1 + Mother 
output : Kid1 + Mother + Self
```

[image]

Comment: Include your own attempt and let us know what error you had or what didn't work as expected.

Comment: What is your problem? Find the words within a string - use `split`. Sort the words? Use an `System.Collections.ArrayList`.

Comment: could you pls check the Image for better understanding

Comment: The task isn't so hard to understand @Grig. The problem is that currently you haven't shown your own attempt and actual problem trying to solve this on your own. And to be honest it's a fun little problem to work on if only this post would be on-topic.

Comment: @Grig You can try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

this blog encourage visitors to do his/her works by own. If anyone face any problem to solve a particular issue then come up with your own attempts. Then we can see your error codes, formulas then correct it. Basically StackOverflow works on trial and error basis. However try below formula if you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd>.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

[image]

- Here `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` creates a valid XML format string to process by `FILTERXML()`.
- XPath argument `//s` return all `s` nodes from XML string.
- `SORT()` function with default parameter sorts all return nodes as `Ascending` order.
- Finally `TRANSPOSE()` function transform data from `vertical` to `horizontal`.

Comment: Perhaps explaining how that works would help many people.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for your good advise. Added short explanation.